# jquery - onclick : show the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to display full screen of a image when i click on thumbnail of it.

Images are hardcoded using IMG tag and having class **.imagethumb**

Images are displayed as thumbnail and when I click on the thumb it should display in a div called **#preview** , inside **#preview** I have a IMG tag to display the full screen of clicked image.

How can I achieve it in jquery ?

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried

Comment: You can find many jquery plugins that will do that for you, for instance [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Comment: I want to try by writing simple jquery. Since I am beginner I want to try my own. Please help me

Comment: If you want to try on your own, go ahead and get started: come back when you have a code question to ask. Having someone write the whole thing for you is not going to help you learn, and you have at least one link with an example you can look at.

Comment: '<img class="imagethumb" src="images/bird.jpg"><img class="imagethumb" src="images/building.jpg">' I want to fetch these images onclick event. how to get image src in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.imagethumb').click(function()
{
    $('#preview').find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Once any of your thumbnails with the class `.imagethumb` are clicked, the `src` attribute of the `img` element inside your `#preview` div is set to the `src` element of the (clicked) thumbnail.

Comment: I mean, could you click on the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that. I will get more reputation and it's considered [basic etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

You should give Simplemodal or Fancybox a try.

Comment: I want to try by writing simple jquery. Since I am beginner I want to try my own. Please help me

Comment: I am done with my gallery layout design and also the basic jquery functionality such as click and fade events are working fine.

Now I want to create a thumbnail filmstrip horizontally , As of now I have 5 hard-coded images and when I click on thumbnail it shows the enlarged image. have a look http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/76/36picture1.png

on load I want to show only 5 images, when I click on next button it should show next 5 images.
Please guide me to achieve it.  I have next and previous buttons having **#next** and **#prev** id

Comment: I suggest you post this up as a new question so it's exposed to more people. It will also help if you include any research efforts you have carried out.